# Connecting RC522 RFID to Arduino Yun

Tags: arduino, rfid, spi, arduino-yun

I'm trying to connect my RC522 RFID reader (http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/MFRC522) to my Arduino Yun.
Unfortunately it doesn't work because the SPI connection seems to be different from the Arduino Uno (accodring to Google). On my Uno it works fine but not on my Yun. To be honest, I'm not very experienced yet with SPI/ICSP so I have no idea how to get the reader running on my Yun :(

It would be really great if someone could give me some help or point me in te right direction.

Thank you very much in advance!! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks Arduino YUN has different pinout than Arduino UNO (look on Google pics). You have to rewire sketch accroding to your board.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration works for me...

```
RST/Reset RST  => D9
SPI SS SDA(SS) => D10
SPI MOSI MOSI  => ICSP-4
SPI MISO MISO  => ICSP-1
SPI SCK SCK    => ICSP-3
```

gnd to gnd & 3.3v to 3.3v

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

SPI: on the ICSP header. These pins support SPI communication using the SPI library. Note that the SPI pins are not connected to any of the digital I/O pins as they are on the Uno, They are only available on the ICSP connector. This means that if you have a shield that uses SPI, but does NOT have a 6-pin ICSP connector that connects to the Yún's 6-pin ICSP header, the shield will not work.

So to summarize, you must use the ICSP header not the IO pins